# What does SPJ stand for in MySQL parlance?

Tags: mysql, ndbcluster, terminology

MySQL has a lot of references to [SPJ in MySQL including in official Oracle slides](http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/36/MySQL%20Cluster%20and%20Pushdown-joins%20_In%20Pursuit%20of%20the%20Holy%20Grail_%20Presentation.pdf) but I can't find what it actually stands for. I see it show up in a few blogs too.

I looked in [the source](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/71f48ab393bce80a59e5a2e498cd1f46f6b43f9a/storage/ndb/src/kernel/blocks/dbspj/DbspjMain.cpp) and found nothing.

**What does SPJ stand for?**

Comment: Don't know the answer, but in the header here: http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/trying-out-mysql-push-down-join-spj-preview it appears to mean `push down join`. What the S has to do with it is a mystery though :-)

Comment: Another mention is: http://johanandersson.blogspot.se/2010/04/mysql-cluster-spj-preview-feedback_27.html "SPJ (preview, not production ready) is a new feature allowing some types of JOINs to be pushed down and executed inside the data nodes! This allows for, in many cases, much faster JOIN execution."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it stands for "*Select Project Join*":

> **What’s in a name?**
>
> If some of this seems familiar but you don’t remember hearing the term
>   “Adaptive Query Localization” before then you’re not going crazy –
>   previous internal names were SPJ (Select Project Join) and Pushed-Down
>   Joins. We just figured that Adaptive Query Localization was more
>   descriptive.

Source: [Dramatically Increased MySQL Cluster JOIN performance with Adaptive Query Localization](https://mysqlhighavailability.com/dramatically-increased-mysql-cluster-join-performance-with-adaptive-query-localization/)